# Question on Particular Solution of Euler Cauchy

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this second order differential equation,

$$x^2y'' + 8xy'-8y = \frac{1}{\sqrt x}$$

General solution is,

$$y = \frac{c_{1}}{x^{8}} + c_{2}x$$

How do I go about finding $y_{PI}$?

Why would it be ok to use $y = \frac{A}{\sqrt x}$

Comment: now you can use the variation of patameters to find $y_p$.

Comment: **Hint**: Use the substitution $z(t)=y(x),\ x=e^t$ to transform the Euler equation (with variable coefficients) into a second order linear ODE, with constant coefficients, for which the method of undetermined coefficients is applicable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write as $L[y]=y''+py'+qy''=f$ and given two linearly independent functions $y_1,y_2$ as you have found in your general solution, use the formula:

$$
y(x)=-y_1(x)\int^x_a \frac{f(t)y_2(t)}{W(t)}dt+y_2(x)\int^x_b \frac{f(t)y_1(t)}{W(t)}dt
$$

Where $a$ and $b$ are chosen to satisfy boundary conditions and $W=y_1y_2'-y_2y_1'$ is the Wronskian.